# How to declare two dimensional and three dimensional vector in Pyomo

Tags: python-3.x, nonlinear-optimization, pyomo

I am trying to solve a optimization problem using Pyomo. For that i need to declare a two dimensional vector and a three dimensional vector . Both of the vectors can store only [0,1].

> > Sri and Xrij
> >
> > R=3 V=8   1<=i,j<=V  1<=r<=R

I tried to to do using range in pyomo

```
model.IDXV = range(v+1)
model.IDXR = range(r+1)
model.x=Var(model.IDXR,model.IDXV,model.IDXV,within=Binary,initialize=0)
model.s=Var(model.IDXR,model.IDXV,within=Binary,initialize=0)
```

I am using the 'ipopt' solver but after execution the value of X and S is in fraction instead of 0 or 1.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: As discussed [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/ipopt-solver-auto-converts-my-binary-variables-to-continuous): `IPOPT` is not suitable for integer and binary problems. It treats binary variables as reals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axel Kemper (in the comments) is correct. `ipopt` is a nonlinear programming solver and automatically assumes that you intend to relax discrete values.

For linear-discrete problems, there are the `cbc` and `glpk` free solvers. `gurobi` and `cplex` are the major commercial solvers.

For nonlinear-discrete problems, `couenne`and `bonmin` are the free solvers. Several other commercial and academic solvers are also available.

Comment: Thank you Qi Chen for help
I have tried couenne solver , But it is taking so much time (4 hrs) to evaluate the result . My problem is non-linear and it have 445 constraints , 248 binary variables and 8 integer variables with bound 1 to 8. Is their any other way to get the results fast.

Comment: Do you need a guaranteed global optimal result?

Comment: Yes, i need global optimal .

Comment: `scip` has a free academic license, so you could try that. Otherwise, `baron` is a good commercial option. Is your problem also non-convex?

Comment: Yes my problem is non-convex . Other than these two what can be possible options to do this work?

Comment: If you have a non-convex problem and you want the guaranteed global optimum, then there are not that many good general-purpose options available. These problems are among the hardest that the community tackles, and a lot of work is still ongoing on effective solution strategies. Potential remedies and workarounds (simplifications, etc) are application-specific.